# React setState not changing state of particular property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

An old dev at my current company recently put his tail between his legs and fled after having to do Typescript/React, leaving me when a bunch of broken code.

My problem now is that I have this TypeScript code that simply removes an item from an array and changes the state:

```
var currentFiles = this.state.openFiles;
    var index = this.state.openFiles.findIndex((f: IFileModel) => f.fileId == fileId)
    currentFiles.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ 
        mode: "gallery",
        openFiles: currentFiles 
    }, () => console.log(this.state.mode));
```

My problem is that the state never updates `mode`, even though the setState *should* do so. Regardless of how I change things up, the `console.log` shows is `0`.

Even putting a breakpoint in the render function, shows me that `mode` is `0`, where it should be `"gallery"`.

This is the initial state:

```
this.state = {
            openFiles: [],
            mode: "gallery",
            categories: [],
            galleryState: {}
        }
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said in a comment that you've been left this code by a dev who recently left the company. I'm afraid they've left you with code breaking two of React's rules: :-)

1. You cannot directly modify state, including objects that `this.state` refers to. You're doing that with `currentFiles.splice(index, 1)`.
2. You're setting new state based on existing state, but not using the callback form of `setState`.

To fix both (see comments):

```
// Use the callback form that receives the up-to-date state as a parameter.
this.setState(
    ({openFiles}) => {
        var index = openFiles.findIndex((f: IFileModel) => f.fileId == fileId)
        // (Do you need an `if (index !== -1)` check here?)
        // Create a *new* array without the entry
        var currentFiles = [...openFiles.slice(0, index), ...openFiles.slice(index+1)];
        // Return the new state
        return {
            mode: "gallery",
            openFiles: currentFiles 
        };
    },
    () => console.log(this.state.mode)
);
```

More in [the state docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Live Example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.removeFileOnClick = this.removeFileOnClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            mode: "main",
            openFiles: [
                {fileId: 1, name: "File 1"},
                {fileId: 2, name: "File 2"},
                {fileId: 3, name: "File 3"},
                {fileId: 4, name: "File 4"},
                {fileId: 5, name: "File 5"}
            ]
        };
    }

    removeFileOnClick(e) {
        const fileId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id");
        this.setState(
            ({openFiles}) => {
                var index = openFiles.findIndex((f) => f.fileId == fileId)
                // (Do you need an `if (index !== -1)` check here?)
                // Create a *new* array without the entry
                var currentFiles = [...openFiles.slice(0, index), ...openFiles.slice(index+1)];
                // Return the new state
                return {
                    mode: "gallery",
                    openFiles: currentFiles 
                };
            },
            () => console.log(this.state.mode)
        );
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <div>
                Mode: {this.state.mode}
                <div>
                    OpenFiles ({this.state.openFiles.length}):
                    <div>{this.state.openFiles.map(file =>
                        <div><button data-id={file.fileId} onClick={this.removeFileOnClick}>X</button>{file.name}</div>
                    )}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: If you don't like the double spread here:

```
var currentFiles = [...openFiles.slice(0, index), ...openFiles.slice(index+1)];
```

you can do it like this instead:

```
var currentFiles = openFiles.slice();
currentFiles.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: Cheers. Great post overall. As mentioned in my edit, it's an old dev's code who recently left me having to refactor his code. I should have spotted that, though.

Comment: @geostocker - I *just* edited that first sentence right before your comment, since I saw your comment on the other answer. :-)

Comment: @geostocker - ...and I just fixed a bug in the post. Forgot to edit out `this.state` in the callback.

Comment: This still sets the state to `0` somehow. The file is removed, but the state is not set to `"gallery"`.

Comment: @geostocker - I'm fairly certain the above is correct, so if the mode isn't being set to `"gallery"`, there must be some other code in play as well. You'll have to narrow it down to a [mcve] for us to help you with that part (by which time I suspect you'll have already figured it out :-) ).

Comment: @geostocker - Just to be sure, I did a live snippet. The problem isn't in the code above.